# I don't understand Docker's "POSTGRES_USER: parameter not set"

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

It is difficult for Docker beginners.

I created a project with cookiecutter-django.

I want to start with Docker after that, but I can't start.

So I run `docker run -it apasn_local_django / bin / ash`

`Entrypoint: line 10: POSTGRES_USER: parameter not set`

Was issued.

The `env_file:` environment variable is set in the docker-compose file.

Isn't it usable in Dockerfile?

What should I do about this solution?

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: apasn_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: apasn_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

entrypoint

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset




if [ -z "${POSTGRES_USER}" ]; then
    base_postgres_image_default_user='postgres'
    export POSTGRES_USER="${base_postgres_image_default_user}"
fi
export DATABASE_URL="postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}"
```

Dockerfile

```
...
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

Comment: You said you used `docker run`. That doesn't have anything to do with your `docker-compose.yml` file. If you don't set the environment variable on the `docker run` command line, it's not going to be set (or just use `docker-compose`).

Comment: After running with "docker-compose up"
“Docker run -t -i apasn_local_django / bin / ash” was executed, but “POSTGRES_USER: parameter not set” appeared.
So does it mean that you need to set environment variables with "docker run"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
set -o nounset

if [ -z "${POSTGRES_USER}" ]; then
  ...
fi
```

Because you have set the `nounset` option, the `if` statement results in an error if `POSTGRES_USER` isn't set in the environment. If you remove the `set -o nounset` command, your `ENTRYPOINT` script will set `POSTGRES_USER` to `postgres` if the environment variable isn't set.

If you expect the `POSTGRES_USER` to be set by one of your environment files, you would need to update your question to show the content of those environment files so that we can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.
The error has been resolved.
I would like to investigate more by myself.
Thank you very much.